# How to count leap years in range [a, b] without loops on C#

Tags: c#, leap-year

Assuming, you have year **a** and year **b**, which are the **range of years** (they are included), how to properly count **leap years** in this **range** without using **loops**? (gregorian calendar)

I wrote this on C#, but i don't think that my code is great. I also used a global variable, but lol, i think there are a solution that is so much better and more elegant than this. I'm just a newbie, so sorry that i'm asking this dumb question.
Also, i don't think you should use DateTime here and etc.

Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    public static int leap_years = 0;
    static void Main()
    {
        do
        {
            int a, b;
            leap_years = 0;
            do Console.Write("Enter a: ");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a) || a < 0);
            do Console.Write("Enter b: ");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b) || b < 0 || a == b || a >= b);
            Console.WriteLine("Leap years: " + countLeapYears(a, b));
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
```

Where `countLeapYears` is

```
    static public int countLeapYears(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            return leap_years;
        else
        {
            if (a % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (a % 100 == 0)
                {
                    if (a % 400 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Year {0} - leap year", a);
                        leap_years++;
                        a += 4;
                        countLeapYears(a, b);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Year {0} - not a leap year", a);
                        a++;
                        countLeapYears(a, b);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Year {0} - leap year", a);
                    leap_years++;
                    a += 4;
                    countLeapYears(a, b);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Year {0} - not a leap year", a);
                a++;
                countLeapYears(a, b);
            }
        }
        return leap_years;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can start by finding the number of years in the range divisible by 4. That overcounts because you have included those divisible by 100, so remove those. Now you have undercounted because you removed those divisible by 400, so add those again.

Comment: You say "without loops" but you're using a recursion, which is essentially the same

Comment: yeah, i guess i should not have used it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we don't have year `0`: `1BC` is followed by `1AD` which *spoils the fun*. However, if we can work with `AD` (positive years) only, you can try something like this:

```
private static int countLeapYears(int from, int to) =>
  (to / 4 - (from - 1) / 4) -
  (to / 100 - (from - 1) / 100) +
  (to / 400 - (from - 1) / 400);
```

Let's test it with respect to naive computation:

```
private static int naiveCount(int from, int to) {
  int result = 0;

  for (int i = from; i <= to; ++i) 
    if (i % 400 == 0 || i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0)
      result += 1;

  return result;
}

...

Random gen = new Random(123);

var result = Enumerable
  .Range(1, 20)
  .Select(i => {
    int to = gen.Next(1590, 2222);
    int from = gen.Next(1590, 2222);

    return (from: Math.Min(from, to), to: Math.Max(from, to));
  })
  .Select(test => $"{test.from} - {test.to} actual: {countLeapYears(test.from, test.to),3} expected: {naiveCount(test.from, test.to),3}");
  
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
2163 - 2212 actual:  12 expected:  12
2059 - 2102 actual:  10 expected:  10
1620 - 2056 actual: 107 expected: 107
1600 - 1684 actual:  22 expected:  22
1713 - 1988 actual:  67 expected:  67
1902 - 2164 actual:  65 expected:  65
1709 - 1881 actual:  42 expected:  42
1639 - 2124 actual: 118 expected: 118
1751 - 1948 actual:  48 expected:  48
1594 - 2184 actual: 144 expected: 144
1605 - 1691 actual:  21 expected:  21
1591 - 2082 actual: 120 expected: 120
1993 - 2066 actual:  18 expected:  18
2022 - 2158 actual:  33 expected:  33
1678 - 1919 actual:  57 expected:  57
1966 - 2128 actual:  40 expected:  40
1635 - 2069 actual: 106 expected: 106
1649 - 1963 actual:  75 expected:  75
1719 - 2169 actual: 110 expected: 110
1847 - 2093 actual:  61 expected:  61
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much. What an awesome answer and solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public int LeapYear(int initialYear, int endYear, int     ref countYear)
{
    if (initialYear > endYear)
    {
         return countYear;
    }
    
    if(DateTime.IsLeapYear(initialYear)
    {
         countYear++;
    }
   
    initialYear++;
    LeapYear(initialYear, endYear, countYear)
}
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation of the code, so the answer is more complete

Comment: I don't think you should use recurson here. As one guy above i the comments told: recursion is just basically the same things as loops